# Reuse CSS class changing some properties

Tags: css, sass

I need to reuse a css class, but change some of its properties conditionally.

For example, i'd like to merge these two classes into one to avoid having duplicated lines (my real world scenario has many more duplicated properties)

```
&__logo-small {
    color: $white;
    display: block;
    max-width: 3rem;

    &--link {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 3rem;
        width: 3rem;  
    }
}

&__logo-big {
    color: $white;
    display: block;
    max-width: 6rem;

    &--link {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 6rem;
        width: 6rem;  
    }
}
```

I find this tricky because the changes happen in different levels. If it was a sinlge level i could use inheritance, but in this case I'm stuck.

Is something like this achievable?

Edit: I'm adding a snippet of HTML for better context.

What I'm trying to do is provide support to two kind of logos.

The old format is called 'logo', the new format is 'desktopLogo'. They are rendered differently.

```
<img *ngIf="logo" class="navbar__logo" [src]="logo" alt="logo">
<a 
  *ngIf="desktopLogo"
  class="navbar__logo"
  (click)="onItemClicked(desktopLogo)"
  [attr.id]="desktopLogo.id"
>
  <img class="navbar__logo--link" [src]="desktopLogo.icon" alt="logo">
</a>
```

Notice that the class navbar__logo--link only applies to the new version.

Thanks everyone for your kind answers, I made it work with Pete's suggestion !

Comment: Could you show your html too please

Comment: @Pete why would you need the HTML? Its a question about how to merge those SASS lines to be shorter. The HTML is completely irrelevant to it.

Comment: @tacoshy so I can see how the link and logo are structure - I'm asuming the link wraps the logo - it allows us to give different answers if that's the case

Comment: @pete nope, the `&` sign in SASS indicates that it is the very same element. It is not a child element as then the ampersand sign in SASS (and LESS) is used to not declare a child element when nesting: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: @tacoshy I know how sass works - see my answer below for the type of difference you could have if you know the structure of the html.  Obviously if it is not nested in that way, the second part of the answer wouldn't be possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using your modifier wrong - the modifier in this case would be small and big.

I would start off with a base class and then just change the bits with the modifiers

```css
&__logo {
  color: $white;
  display: block;
  max-width: 3rem;
  
  &-link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    
    &--big {
      height: 6rem;
      width: 6rem;
    }
  }
  
  &--big {
    max-width: 6rem;
  }
}
```

```html
a normal logo would look like this:
<a href="class__logo-link"><img class="class__logo"></a>

a big logo would look like this:
<a href="class__logo-link class__logo-link--big"><img class="class__logo class__logo--big"></a>
```

If your html is structured like the above, you may want to only put the modifier on the link, then you can do something like this

```css
&__logo {
  color: $white;
  display: block;
  max-width: 3rem;
  
  &-link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    
    &--big {
      height: 6rem;
      width: 6rem;
      
      .class__logo {
         width: 6rem;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
a normal logo would look like this:
<a href="class__logo-link"><img class="class__logo"></a>

a big logo would look like this:
<a href="class__logo-link class__logo-link--big"><img class="class__logo"></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is:

```
&__logo {
  color: $white;
  display: block;
  
  &-small {
    max-width: 3rem;
  }
  
  &-big {
    max-width: 6rem;
  }
  
  &--link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;    
    
    .logo-small & {
        height: 3rem;
        width: 3rem;        
    }
    
    .logo-big & {
        height: 6rem;
        width: 6rem;        
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I may be wrong, you may have tried this already, and this may not quite be what your are asking but I hope I am on the right track. To remove some redundancy and increase reusability, you could abstract the similarities between the two classes into one `logo` class, and then use CSS variables to write the differences elsewhere. I am writing this in normal CSS instead due to personal preferences but feel free to adapt to SCSS:

```css
:root { --clr-light: #FFFFFF; }

.logo:has(.logo-small) { --size-logo: 3rem; }
.logo:has(.logo-big) { --size-logo: 6rem; }

.logo {
    color: var(--clr-light);
    display: block;
    max-width: var(--size-logo);
}

.logo .link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: var(--size-logo);
    width: var(--size-logo);
}
```

A few other tips:

- Setting heights is generally bad practice (according to Kevin Powell) but understandable here as it is an image!
- You may want to change the `.logo .link` to `.logo > .link` if it is only wanted for a direct child.
- I believe `flex-direction: row` is the default so that probably is not needed but I may be wrong!
- `.has()` is not supported in some browsers still so may not be the best way to go. You can use `.logo-big` and `.logo-small`.
- This approach might increase the number of classes you may need to add into the HTML but hopefully for the better to aid styling.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Another edit: `flex-direction: row;` is only needed to improve readability if you have a media query or equivalent that changes it to column.

Comment: would be helpful if you understand how SASS works if you try to answer a SASS question. You make assumptions that refer to missing knowledge about SASS. `--link` is not a class. And specifically not a child-element of that class (`&` => ampersand sign in SASS!). PS `flex-direction:row` is not necessarily redundant. There are frameworks such as React (not React.js) that have column as default. Also, `:has` is only supported around 70%, not a good use for productive code.

Comment: @tacoshy hi! please make sure you read everything before commenting, especially the ":has() is not supported in some browsers still" and the "this may not quite be what your are asking but I hope I am on the right track". I never claimed to be an expert and only "hope[d] to be on the right track", hence is the nature of stack overflow and asking on forums. It is redundant because they did not specify it was with a framework! It is inappropriate to be snarky in comments, but this is SO so don't know what i expected! Finally, thank you for saying my misunderstandings - I will learn for future!